# Confirm Oraclize is not working on Ropsten? (No callback returned)

Tags: solidity, etherscan, ropsten, oracles

I have a contract on Ropsten testnet that was working fine up until 2 hours and 30 minutes ago. I don't believe it is an error on my side because the code hasn't been changed or redeployed.

You can see the oraclize query still being sent out in the internal transactions section of my contract on on Etherscan but there is never any callback returned from Oraclize anymore in the last few hours. Is this assessment correct? I've contacted Oraclize support on their Gitter channel as well.

Here is the contract on Etherscan: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x8466bc490d87b01d7b0d0f9b5682a806e49966d6

Thanks for any help!